# Deploy Nextjs locally

Tags: next.js, deployment

I have a Nextjs application that I am building for a client. Our agreement was only for the application not source code. In react I used to just send over the build files but when I build my next app and try to copy the .next folder and run, I get various errors. How can I build my app and deploy it on a local server without exposing my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the output: export parameter in your next.config.js file.

Documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports

Comment: "Features that require a Node.js server, or dynamic logic that cannot be computed during the build process, are not supported" I have an entire backend including models, trpc, nextauth and so on